# removing object from arraylist leaves null

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, nullpointerexception, null

I have a function called resolveClash, which I send an array 
(in this case - combinsFinal) with 2 or more objects in it of type ModuleLecturerStudentCombination (this is my own class). Essentially what the resolveClash function does is it puts the array into an arraylist, removes the first element/object in the array and then returns the list. However, when I inspect the state of the returned value in debug mode (eclipse), it shows that a null value has been added onto the end of the arraylist.

I have looked up "removing objects correctly" etc, however, everything I have tried so far doesn't get rid of the null. The null appears after I perform the remove. I have thoroughly checked that there is not a null being passed in etc. This is a problem because when I use this and iterate through it later, it picks up a null and gives me a nullpointerexception error. Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

[picture displaying problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWaab.jpg)

```
resolveClash(combinsFinal);


public ArrayList <ModuleLecturerStudentCombination> resolveClash(ModuleLecturerStudentCombination[] combinationArr){
    ArrayList<ModuleLecturerStudentCombination> copyCombinationList = new ArrayList<ModuleLecturerStudentCombination>(Arrays.asList(combinationArr));
    copyCombinationList.remove(0);
    return copyCombinationList;
}
```

Comment: Are you using eclipse or similar and looking at the result in the Debug perspective?

Comment: `return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(combinationArr).subList(1, combinationArr.length()));` would be easier.

Comment: How do you ***know*** the returned `ArrayList` contains a `null`? How do you know the null wasn't already in the array you passed to the method?  In debug mode you will see implementation details of the `ArrayList`, including entries in the backing array that are NOT part of the list's value.

Comment: I have updated the post to answer these questions

Comment: @michaelskellig510 you should add the additional code in the question rather than using a picture (especially since the problem seems to be in the additional code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...when I inspect the state of the returned value in debug mode, it shows that a null value has been added onto the end of the arraylist

This is the normal way it works. The data within the `ArrayList` is stored in an array, which then is wrapped in the class to behave in the way a list does. If you add elements and the array is to small it will create a bigger one and copy the objects.

However if you remove some, it wont create a new shorter array, but simply leave some free spots at the end, but only give you access to the first ones that should be their. In the Debug mode you should also see a variable called `size` which tells you which part of the array is still part of the list.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the `ArrayList` method [`toArray(T [])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray-T:A-) is not returning a new array. From the documentation:

> [...] If the list fits in the specified array, it is returned therein.
>   Otherwise, a new array is allocated with the runtime type of the
>   specified array and the size of this list.
>
> If the list fits in the
>   specified array with room to spare (i.e., the array has more elements
>   than the list), the element in the array immediately following the end
>   of the collection is set to null. [...]

The array `combinsFinal` has greater size than the list so the result is returned directly into it with an additional `null`. In this case no new array with the correct size is created.

To avoid this, since you cannot change the size of an array, you could create a new one with the same size of the list, then this would work correctly:

```
combinsFinal = new ModuleLecturerStudentCombination[temp.size()];
temp.toArray(combinsFinal);
```

or alternatively just pass an array with no size so the method will be forced to create and return a new array with the correct size:

```
combinsFinal = temp.toArray(new ModuleLecturerStudentCombination[0]);
```